# What permissions do I need to do a mysqlcheck on all tables?

Tags: mysql, permissions

I'm trying to run [`mysqlcheck`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlcheck.html), and I want to run it on all tables, so I'm passing it the `-A` option. However it's silently skipping all tables that it's doesn't have permission to view.

Is there some 'catch all' permission that I can give that account that will let it scan all tables?

In the principles of best practice, I want to give this account as few permissions as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Granting SELECT and INSERT on all tables should allow you to run `mysqlcheck`.

The link you posted to `mysqlcheck` lists the commands it calls:

- [CHECK TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/check-table.html)
- [REPAIR TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/repair-table.html)
- [ANALYZE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/analyze-table.html)
- [OPTIMIZE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimize-table.html)

If you click through to the documentation for each of those commands, you will find the permissions required by each of them.  Most require both SELECT and INSERT, some only require SELECT.

So GRANT ALL should not be necessary.

Comment: I couldn't see the permissions on the page for CHECK TABLE

Comment: It's down in the comments.  "CHECK TABLE" requires SELECT privileges only.